# Adding Esri Elevation to QGIS, possible?

Tags: qgis

I can add World Imagery through Layer > Add Layer > Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer, using [this URL](http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer). Is this somehow possible with Esri's World Elevation layer (info see [here](http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation)) as well?

When I try to add it as layer using [this URL](http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/GlobeServer/), QGIS does return a layer ("Elevation(90m/1km)"), but can't add it (error "Layer is not valid"). I guess it's because it's a GlobeServer?

Comment: I don't think the Globe Service is supported